# How to remove a HTML element with a button click and then add it again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove an element when I click the button and then add it again when I click the button again.

Don't get me wrong I don't want to "hide" the element I want to remove it.

I'm not really sure why this is not working but, my guess is that this creates a reference and once I delete the original element there would be nothing to add.

Is there any way to fix this using only native javascript?

```js
       function sortClick() {
        var classes = document.getElementById('btn').classList;        
        var myNode = document.getElementById('myNode');
        var clone = myNode.cloneNode(true);


        if(!classes.contains('firstClick')){
        classes.add("firstClick");   
       myNode.parentNode.removeChild(myNode); 

          }

        else if(classes.contains('firstClick')) {
        classes.remove('firstClick');   
        document.body.appendChild( clone );

        
        }
  
        };
```

```css
#btn {
cursor: pointer;
}
.firstClick {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='btn' onClick='sortClick()'>click</div>
<div id=myNode>removed then added</div>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as hiding the node, @HalilÇakar which he said he does not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem because you don't store the element in a global variable but using a local one. Check this out. Hope it works for you.

```js
var clone;

function sortClick() {
  var classes = document.getElementById('btn').classList;
  if (document.getElementById('myNode')) {

    var myNode = document.getElementById('myNode');
    clone = myNode.cloneNode(true);
  }

  if (!classes.contains('firstClick')) {
    classes.add("firstClick");
    myNode.parentNode.removeChild(myNode);

  } else if (classes.contains('firstClick')) {
    classes.remove('firstClick');
    document.body.appendChild(clone);


  }

};
```

```css
#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.firstClick {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='btn' onClick='sortClick()'>click</div>
<div id='myNode'>removed then added</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain further? The adding was working just fine but the removing was not.

Comment: @Aifa, When you fire a function the first time you declare and assign your variables to default values. Next time you run the function `sortClick` you redeclare your variable again and set its to default values. So when you try to paste the removed element there's no data in variable `clone` because there's no element on a page(you've already removed it first time). You can fix this by using global variable in a global scope. In that case you can access to a global variable and use already stored element data to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry about that comment earlier.
I've just prepared a pen for you.

Here you can see :=)

Right about explanation;
in your code everytime you sortClick() it re-tries to `cloneNode` from `myNode` which in the second time it's null. That's why you had that error =)

```js
var clone;
function sortClick() {
  var classes = document.getElementById('btn').classList;
  var myNode = document.getElementById('myNode');
  if(!clone) {
    clone = myNode.cloneNode(true); 
  }


  if (!classes.contains('firstClick')) {
    classes.add("firstClick");
    myNode.parentNode.removeChild(myNode);
  }
  else if (classes.contains('firstClick')) {
    classes.remove('firstClick');
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
  }
};
```

https://codepen.io/halilcakar/pen/WNQLqGq?editors=1111

Comment: it's okay, thank you for your effort :))  I wanted some explanation not just a solution but thanks anyway!